# How do I display an HTML block using hover in CSS?

Tags: html, css

When the sections for information are displayed, they show on the background just fine, but when I try the hovering display trick, nothing works.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
.info-top .about:hover + .info .about-d {
display: inline;
color: #FFF;
}
```

This isn't being parsed, and display: none is the only part that's working.

http://jsfiddle.net/jcd63/ -- My code for the applicable pieces

I've tested it on Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox (newest versions) and it's not working. -responding to anyone asking if i have an older browser

Comment: it's working in the fiddle. which browser you are using? this may not work in older version.

Comment: no not working for me too,by the way i write my code in the answers,may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to display image then please use:

`display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

u should define hover elements into about class and then

doing like so:

```
.info-top .about:hover > .info .about-d{
visibility:visible
}
```

or using `display:block` also using `position:absulote` to show better
,here a Edited [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcd63/12/)

Comment: could you elaborate on defining hover elements into about class and then--?
nothing's working, by the way

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with your markup

the selector X + Y

> It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the
>   former element.

.info .about-d is not preceded by .about:hover.

the stylesheet is cascading. yours goes the other way around